# By accident deleted /dev folder on android (LG G2 phone). how can i bring back system to life?

Tags: data-recovery, development

Hello good people of universe!
Someone asked before on this website "what will happen if i delete /dev folder on android?", its kinda funny, but i really deleted it, but it was by accident while installing custom rom using TWRP recovery. Im really messed up now, system stucks at LG Logo screen. I dont know what to do, seems that PC can't detect my phone at all. But i can enter to firmware update by pushing up+power button. Can someone help me with that question ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hard system reset would reset all existing files of the device.

Backing up your files before you committed to the hard reset would be the best course of action for you.

There are step-by-step instructions to assist you in performing the hard reset on the verizon page, but this will work for all carriers as it is the same device: https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-104173/.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. not sure it will help, but I definitely try it tomorow! Thanks once again.

Comment: It wasca solution,  you are my hero.  Thanks alot.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.